# get the position / coordinates and size of text displayed on the screen in TKINTER

Tags: text, tkinter, coordinates, python-imaging-library, bounding-box

We are about to conduct an eye tracking study where we will try to evaluate gaze on specific words displayed on the screen.
I have many .txt files that need to be converted to images and displayed on the screen for the experiment.
I am trying to find a way to layout the text so that I will know the exact position and length of each word on the screen.

I thought of using tkinter to layout the text inside a canvas.
I am not so sure if this is a good way and how to convert the output to an image.
An alternative might be to use PIL.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a canvas, with [`bbox`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) you can return the bounding box of the items.

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback(event, text_id):
    print event.widget.bbox(text_id)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=200)
text = "the lazy dog jumped over the brown fox"
offset = 20
for word in text.split(" "):
    text_id = canvas.create_text(offset, 50, text=word, anchor=W)
    bbox = canvas.bbox(text_id)
    offset += bbox[2] - bbox[0] + 5
    canvas.tag_bind(text_id, "<Button-1>",
                    lambda e, i=text_id: callback(e, i))
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks ! We eventually decides to use CSS for positioning the words and display in HTML.